# Seleccionar el top 1 de varios registros

Tags: sql-server

Buen día, estaba haciendo una consulta en sql server 2008 de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT  top 1 *
FROM Mitabla WHERE id_detalle = 25  ORDER BY fecha desc
```

Pero si en mi tabla hay  muchos diferentes id_detalle se vuelve tedioso correr uan consulta por cada id_detalle diferente cambie la consulta por la siguiente

```
SELECT  top 1 *
    FROM Mitabla WHERE id_detalle in (25,26)  ORDER BY fecha desc
```

Pero solo me arroja el registro del id_detalle  26

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: al utilizar top, estás delimitando a que tu consulta devuelva el número de registros exacto que pone el número, top 1 SIEMPRE devolverá solo 1 registro, independientemente de que pueda encontrar n registros que concuerden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este caso, es necesario agregar una columna que pueda indicar cual es la primer fila. Esto se hace mediante la función `ROW_NUMBER()`. Sin embargo, como no podemos hacer referencia directa a esa columna desde el `WHERE`, tenemos que usar una tabla derivada que puede ser en forma de CTE o subconsulta.

Aquí dejo el ejemplo usando una CTE.

```
WITH miCTE AS(
    SELECT  *, --traemos toda la tabla
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_detalle ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS fila
    FROM Mitabla 
    --Aquí podemos agregar condiciones adicionales
)
SELECT * --Se cambia por las columnas que necesitamos para ocultar la columna 'fila'
FROM miCTE
WHERE fila = 1;
```

Comment: Disculpa podrías explicarme la funcion que tiene with en esta consulta

Comment: Es la sintaxis de la CTE, que suelo explicarla como una vista (el tipo de objeto) en linea (o sea en el mismo código). Puedes obtener información detallada en [la ayuda de SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

Existen muchas alternativas para obtener lo que indicas.

Una de ellas, con el escenario que muestras, puede ser, obtener la maxima fecha agrupando por id_detalle y después mezclarlo con los datos originales.

```
Create table dbo.MiTabla (id int, id_detalle int, fecha date, tipo char(1));
Go

Insert into dbo.MiTabla (id, id_detalle, fecha, tipo)
values
(1 ,25,'20210501','C'),
(2 ,27,'20210501','B'),
(3 ,24,'20210501','C'),
(4 ,25,'20210401','B'),
(5 ,24,'20210401','B'),
(6 ,24,'20210401','A'),
(7 ,27,'20210401','A'),
(8 ,25,'20210301','A'),
(9 ,26,'20210301','B'),
(10,26,'20210101','C');
GO

With c
     As (Select id_detalle
              , Max(fecha) As fecha
                From dbo.mitabla As a
                Group By id_detalle)
     Select b.*
            From c
                 Inner Join dbo.mitabla As b 
                 On c.id_detalle = b.id_detalle And c.fecha = b.fecha;
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Esto puede causar un problema si hay más de una fila con esa fecha y ese detalle.

Comment: @LuisCazares Pero no es el escenario que han planteado. Además del mismo modo, en la sentencia del row_number tal cual la has escrito no puedes determinar habiendo varios elementos con la misma fecha para la misma partición, si el motor te devolverá una vez como fila 1 un id y en otra ejecución como fila 1 otro diferente.

Comment: Sin embargo, mi solución sí es lo que se ha planteado. Mientras que el tuyo refleja la opción `TOP 1 WITH TIES`. No es que tu solución sea mala, solo que hay que tener en cuenta el comportamiento ante distintas posibilidades.